# Oracle 11g database not connecting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

i installed oracle 11g database express edition on my windows 7 (32 bit) pc . It was successfully installed but now when i try to open it , Firefox gives me following error.
"unable to connect."

So please reply to this post as soon as possible to open Oracle as without this , i can't go ahead in learning it. I m just a beginner.

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by: "... when i try to open it ..."

Comment: when i try open oracle application express homepage in firefox then it gives me above error.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .  If you want someone to post "as soon as possible," please provide sufficient details.    Are the oracle services started on your machine?  Did you read the install docs - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Check if u can open **SQLPLUS**
if yes, change the port of ORACLE web server by using 
**connect / as sysdba**
**DBMS_XDB.sethttpport('9090');**

Answer (score 1):

open run SQL command line or in your cmd writes: sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

for both cases:

```
SQL> conn
Enter user-name:
Enter password:
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL DEVELOPER

Default connection for oracle 11g

go to connection>New Connection

Connection Name = HR or Use any name

User name = hr

Password = Your Password (This is the password that you selected during the installation of the of Oracle 11g)

Check the "Save" option

role: default

port 1521

SID : orcl

If you want to create the SYSDBA Account ( Administrator account)

Connection Name = admin ORCL or Use any name

User name = sys

Password = Your Password (This is the password that you selected during the installation of the of Oracle 11g)

role: sysdba( from the drop down)

port 1521

SID : orcl

TEST and Save Connect

Just in case if your HR account is locked because you have connected multiple number of times than you can fix this by logging into your SYS DBA account

In the objects list on your list go to the OTHER USERS and

GO to HR Account > RT Click

EDIT USER

Choose the password youlike

and UN CHECK The account locked and Uncheck the Password Expired options if they are checked in

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the you install as a user and not as admin. Even if u have admin privileges, it won't do.

Also, after this error comes then the issue is that the port 8080 is being used by another application.
1.) First of all, stop that app.
2.) Rest Oracle Port

```
SQL> begin
 2    dbms_xdb.sethttpport('9090');
 3  end;
 4  /
```

PS: I read one thread it says that don't use @ in the password also.

Hope it helps :)